# How to override background color of body without changing the existing background color?

Tags: html, css

how do i change the body background color red without overriding css or removing the css property?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/vNkRh.png

Comment: How do you expect to change something if you cannot override or remove it?  This question makes no sense

Comment: You could set a HTML background color using `<body bgcolor="#ff0000">...</body>`

Comment: @Werner I would class that as overriding it, besides the bgcolor attribute is deprectaed and should not be used: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement/bgColor

Comment: Okay, Another approach: Create a wrapper in the body tag which has a different background-color and make it full size. Or set a background-image which is a 1x1px *blue* image and let it repeat.

Comment: just add background-color white to each element. in this way you are not overriding. background color red is still there but not visible

Answer (score 1):

`this is a challenge you should not overide the styles using html, css, Javasript or Jquery ...this is a interview question...is there any other way possible?`

From the challange we can assume this is trick question.

You should tell your interviewer that this can't be done without overriding CSS, but if he meant how would you do it without changing css file directly you would use **inline css** or **javascript**.

Here is inline css example:

```
<body style='background: blue'>
```

Here is JS > JQ example:

```
$('body').css('background','blue');
```

Code in action http://jsbin.com/latajuquwo/edit?html,js,output

Comment: this is a challenge you should not overide the styles using html, css, Javasript or Jquery ...this is a interview question...is there any other way possible?

Comment: Nice challenge: "Please do something with this technology without using it"

Comment: @vinayjoseph Instead of downvoting me you should have clarified your question.

Comment: My interviewer will say the answer tomorrow..there is a solution without overriding or using js...

Comment: I presume It's a trick question I will edit my answer, so you can answer him.

Comment: you can use css but you should not override i mean you can use any css property other than body { background-color: red}

Comment: @vinayjoseph As you can see I've changed my answer also I am using 'background' not 'background-color' if that makes any difference for you.

Comment: my interviewer says you are still overriding...there is a way without overriding. I should solve this without overriding. you can use css but no overriding

Comment: @vinayjoseph You can use background image css property. body {
  background: red;
  background-image: url('https://placebear.com/g/200/300');
}

Comment: just add background-color white to each section. in this way you are not overriding. background color red is still there but not visible

Comment: You are overriding it with that, you are just changing background-color to white. I don't think you understood question correctly or your  interviewer  didn't explain it properly.

Comment: i am just changing the background color of each div overiding means you are changing the property of the same thing

Comment: Solved it by adding background-color white to each element. In this way, you are not overriding. background color red and even it will not be visible just reduce the opacity of newly added bg color you can see the red background color. This way you are not overriding the existing color.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do so. The **only** way styles are defined is with CSS.

---

If you want to do it without changing the existing CSS-file, use inline-styling (this will override the property from the file **for that element only**). If you neither have access to HTML nor CSS, one of the other two posted answers are what you are looking for.

Comment: this is a challenge you should not overide the styles using html, css, Javasript or Jquery ...this is a interview question...is there any other way possible

Comment: this is a challenge you should not overide the styles using html, css, Javasript or Jquery ...this is a interview question...is there any other way possible

Comment: You can't do something in CSS without using CSS. Idk who asked that, but either the question was asked in the wrong way, it is a trap question or he/she doesn't understand html/css

Comment: you just have to remove the background color ...without overriding..my interviewer will post the answer tomorrow

Comment: you can use css but you should not override i mean you can use any css property other than body { background-color: red}

Comment: just add background-color white to each element. in this way you are not overriding. background color red is still there but not visible

Comment: Solved it by adding background-color white to each element. In this way, you are not overriding. background color red and even it will not be visible just reduce the opacity of newly added bg color you can see the red background color. This way you are not overriding the existing color.

Comment: _Note: I copied the same comment to your answer as you wrote the same there_ 1) you are not changing the background color as asked 2) The red only disappears if you have a wrapper around **everything** and set `body {margin:0}`, which makes next to no sense in most architectures 3) If you add that to the `body`-tag you are overriding the style

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if I understand your question, but you can try a JavaScript approach?

JS:

```
document.getElementById("yourElementID").style.backgroundColor = "yourColor";
```

JQuery

```
$("#yourElementID").css("background-color", "yourColor");
```

If you can, try to explain a little better what your issue is so we can provide the appropriate support.

Comment: this is a challenge you should not overide the styles using html, css, Javasript or Jquery ...this is a interview question...is there any other way possible

Comment: you can use css but you should not override i mean you can use any css property other than body { background-color: red}

Comment: just add background-color white to each element. in this way you are not overriding. background color red is still there but not visible

Comment: Solved it by adding background-color white to each element. In this way, you are not overriding. background color red and even it will not be visible just reduce the opacity of newly added bg color you can see the red background color. This way you are not overriding the existing color.

Comment: No idea why people would downvote answeres to such a badly explained question.. oh well.

Answer (score -1):

Solved it by adding background-color white to each element. In this way, you are not overriding. background color red and even it will not be visible just reduce the opacity of newly added bg color you can see the red background color. This way you are not overriding the existing color.

Comment: 1) you are not changing the background color as asked 2) The red only disappears if you have a wrapper around everything and set body {margin:0}, which makes next to no sense in most architectures 3) If you add that to the body-tag you are overriding the style